# Анимировать прозрачность эффекта из ресурсов - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Есть `UserControl` и колекция с ресурсами `ResourceDictionary`

Внутри `ResourceDictionary` у меня вот такое

```
<DropShadowEffect x:Key="LightingEffect" x:Name="Lighting" Color="#FF4BC7FF" Direction="0" 
                  RenderingBias="Performance" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0"/>
<Style x:Key="userControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyType}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="MustBeSelected" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Duration="00:00:03" AutoReverse="True">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0.5" To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="LightingEffect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

При компиляции пишет мне нельзя установить `Storyboard.TargetName`, в чем проблема?

Comment: Может, в типе `MyType` нету ничего с именем `LightingEffect`? Покажите ваш `MyType`.

Comment: @VladD: Это тип UserControl, и в нем есть`<UserControl.Effect><DropShadowEffect x:Name="LightingEffect"...`, или так работать не будет?

Comment: Если я правильно помню, нет, потому что в таком виде `LightingEffect` — локальное имя внутри контрола. Почему бы вместо этого не использовать `Storyboard.Target`?